# Automate csv file upload into SQL Server with changing file name

Tags: sql-server, database, windows, import, etl

I want to automate uploading certain files into my SQL Server every day, but each file has a different name.

I was researching and found a simple way was to schedule a bulk insert statement to run every day, but I don't know how to implement the file name change in the query. I'm not too familiar with using Windows command prompt but I'm open to using that as a solution.

The file name change is something like `mmddyyyyfile` with the `mmddyyyy` part changing to correspond with the day's date.

Comment: You generate a file name based on the current date - `replace(convert(char(10), @x, 101), '/', '')` where @x is the current datetime (or any other datetime that you wish to import). This will require dynamic sql which will surely by used by solutions you can find with some simple searching.

Answer (score 0):

We use this technique in our system bulk loads when we have regular file extracts to import, similar to what you describe in your situation.  **If you have access to and are willing to use** `xp_cmdshell` (which is sounds like you are) then doing something like this allows for dynamic filenames and you don't have to worry about what your date pattern is:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @cmdstr VARCHAR(1024) = 'dir c:\upload /B'; --set your own folder path here
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(1024);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #CmdOutput;
CREATE TABLE #CmdOutput (CmdOutput varchar(1024));

INSERT #CmdOutput EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmdstr;

DECLARE FILES CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT CmdOutput
FROM  #CmdOutput
WHERE CmdOutput IS NOT NULL;

OPEN FILES;
FETCH NEXT FROM FILES INTO @FileName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    /*
    Use dynamic SQL to do your bulk load here based on the value of @FileName
    */
    FETCH NEXT FROM FILES INTO @FileName;
END;

CLOSE FILES;
DEALLOCATE FILES;

DROP TABLE #CmdOutput;
```

This will blindly take any file in the folder and include it in the cursor iterations.  If the folder containing your .csv files will have something else that you don't then you can easily add filtering to the WHERE clause that defines the cursor to limit the files.

Finally, the obligatory warning about enabling and using `xp_cmdshell` on your SQL Server instance.  I won't go into the details about that here (there is ample information that can be searched out), but suffice to say it is a security concern and needs to be used with the understanding of risks involved.